# Header active class isn't being set correctly

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

On my [website](http://commerce.moussaieff.info) when you click on one of the navbar links it goes to the correct area of the html document but it shows on the navbar the wrong active class. But when you scroll down a tiny bit it will change to the correct color / class.

I tried changing the -40 to -9 in custom.js line 45 and it works correctly but the title is now slightly cut off.

My [github](http://github.com/manu354/commerce)

Comment: Can you hare some link or code to explain your problem better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is in your website, when you click on the navbar links, it doesn't scroll completely to that section, **because of the navbar height**. You have used a template, so according to how they have written the page-scroll code, they have purposely scrolled a little above the section considering the height of the navbar. To avoid this

**Solution 1**

1 - Go to your `custom.js` line number 45.

2 - Increase the value of `scrollTop: target.offset().top - 40` to `scrollTop: target.offset().top` or may be more, depending on you.

But if you do this obviously the title of the section will be hidden behind the navbar. I have suggested another cleaner solution below.

**Solution 2**

You can simply add a `margin-top: 80px;` to each section (statistics, overview etc.).

Comment: Yeah I did that but then the links go too far down

Comment: Solution 2 I provided won't scroll too far. I have made and tested the change directly on your website and it seems to work well.

Comment: Ok thanks, do you know of any other solutions?

Comment: <section id="stats" style="margin-top: 80px;">, like this.

Comment: Thanks! Kind of a hack, but it will do!

Comment: `scrollTop: target.offset().top + 40px`, this is not. try this. Tell me what happens - on **line number 45 in custom.js** file

Comment: it says unexpected identiefier

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103816/discussion-between-nikhil-nanjappa-and-manu).